# How to check if Preference exist

Tags: java, android, menu, android-preferences

I am dividing Preference menu into three parts. How to check if **"update_button"** exist before creating `ClickListener`, because i'm getting `NullPointerException`, if i'm going to fragment where is no **"update_button"**. Or there are other way? Thank you for your time and answers.

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle aSavedState) {
        super.onCreate(aSavedState);
        Context anAct = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        int thePrefRes = anAct.getResources().getIdentifier(
                getArguments().getString("pref-resource"), "xml", anAct.getPackageName());
        addPreferencesFromResource(thePrefRes);
        try {
            Preference button = (Preference) findPreference("update_button");
            button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update Done.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check if `button` is `null`.

Example:

```
Preference button = (Preference) findPreference("update_button");
if (button != null) {
    button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
        new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            // code
        });
}
```

Comment: Oh...So simple,somehow i thought problem is 
Preference button = (Preference) findPreference("update_button");
Thank you.